# problemas con ireport en netbeans con The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, ireport

estoy tratando de compilar un reporte con ireport en netbeans pero me da el siguiente error al compilarlo:

> Compilation exceptions: com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.errorhandler.ProblemItem@44d82e55  The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
> /* ^ 1 errors      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:191)     at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:499)     at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)     at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)     at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)     at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
> Compilation running time: 240

ya intente cambiando el jdk que necesito pero no funciona, estoy usando netbeans 13 y ireport 4.0.2 usando en el proyecto el jdk 7, porque es lo que utilizan para el proyecto pero no me deja compilar los reportes, alguien podria ayudarme si le ha pasado esto

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. No entiendo por qué si usas iReport4 (que es standalone), estás compilando en netbeans. Si compilas el reporte en iReport te sale ese error? Cuando tienes tu project Java en Netbeans y compilas el reporte, el archivo `.jasper` va a quedar ahí en tu proyecto para que lo usen tus tareas Ant/Maven/Gradle/ loque sea. Lo otro: Prueba en Report properties, revisando el _report language_, prueba cambiándolo a Java si no esta así, o a groovy si está en Java.

Comment: hola @Alfabravo, es que un projecto en jsp con conexion en oracle, estoy editando los reportes dentro del netbeans por que es donde se encuentran los reportes y me lanza ese error, al abrirlo directo en el ireport 4.0.2 si abre y compila se supone pero me abre en blanco el documento, por eso es que no lo estoy haciendo directo en el ireport, ya probe lo de cambiar el language pero sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 2):

El error que se muestra:

> Compilation exceptions:
> com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.errorhandler.ProblemItem@44d82e55 The
> type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced
> from required .class files

se debe generalmente a que usas una versión de Java no soportada. Al usar NetBeans 13 **probablemente tu proyecto está configurado para usar una versión de Java que no tienes instalada**, revisa que configuración tiene tu proyecto y asegúrate instalarla, esto debe resolver el problema.

Por cierto, te sugiero usar como mínimo Java 8 para Netbeans 13.